# Web Hosting Service That Supports JSP/Tomcat Deployment?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets, web-hosting

I'm looking for a web hosting service that supports JSP/Tomcat servlet deployment like [MochaHost](https://mochahost.com/webhosting.php).

Are there any other up-to-date web hosting services you've come accross that offer those types of support?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform is great and affordable for this. 
Here's a tomcat solution:
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bitnami-launchpad/tomcatstack

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner). It has many other options too,